# Android AES encryption and decryption

Tags: android, aes

I have found hundreds of examples of Android AES encryption and decryption but I am unable to make them work, even the simplest. The following code does some encryption and decryption but it spits out garbage after decrypting the encrypted text. Can you please take a look and tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks

```
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGenerator.init(128, new SecureRandom());
SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

String plainText = "This is supposed to be encrypted";
String plainKey = Base64.encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);

//encrypt
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
String encryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

//decrypt
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
byte[]decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
String decryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(decryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: decryptedBytes should be the same as plainText.getBytes(). So just convert decryptedBytes back to a String and you should have plainText back.

Comment: Your code works fine. What @greenapps said. Instead of `Base64.encodeToString(..)`, try printing the output of `new String(decryptedBytes)`, you'll see that it's the value you were looking for.

Comment: Please be aware that this AES implementation as it stands does not give you good data protection. It is using AES in ECB mode, which is very weak. You have to use CBC mode, and to make that strong you have to use a SecureRandom value for the Initialization Vector (IV). It's a bit too much for a comment to explain the details, but if you google "Java AES CBC mode" you get some reasonable articles.

Comment: Yep, that is the second step, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Barend answer works:
Your code works fine. What @greenapps said. Instead of Base64.encodeToString(..), try printing the output of new String(decryptedBytes), you'll see that it's the value you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SecretKeySpec sks = null;
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("Complex Key for encryption".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        sks = new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES secret key spec error");
    }

    // Encode the original data with AES
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(theTestText.getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES encryption error");
    }
    TextView tvencoded = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textitem2);
    tvencoded.setText("[ENCODED]:\n" +
            Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT) + "\n");

    // Decode the encoded data with AES
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(encodedBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES decryption error");
    }
    TextView tvdecoded = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textitem3);
    tvdecoded.setText("[DECODED]:\n" + new String(decodedBytes) + "\n");
```